# http-server npm module serving wrong files by default

Tags: node.js, localhost, node-modules, httpserver

i am using http-server https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

I am using src folder as the path.
But the server is starting directly at Project folder listing the directories.

How can i server src folder.

My folder structure is

Project
    package.json
    src
      index.html

And this is my package.json

```
{
 "name": "dashboard-ng-starfleet",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "http-server ./src -o -p 9000"
 },
 "repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": ""
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "homepage": "",
 "devDependencies": {
 "http-server": "^0.10.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: What does your `http-server` output?

Comment: Its listing all the folder and files in Project folder on a webpage

Comment: From the terminal. Paste the output.

Comment: Hey, Its working i change the "start": "http-server ./src -o -p 9000" to 
"start" : "http-server 'src' -o -p 9000" and had to do hard reload of the page.